# Load OSM data into PostgreSQL using Python-OGR

Tags: python, postgresql, openstreetmap, ogr

I want to load OSM data into PostgreSQL database using Python script. When I am trying this Python script, it doesn't load OSM data into database. Can anyone guide me? I know how to load data in PostgreSQL using osmosis but currently I am looking for something using Python.

```
import psycopg2
from osgeo import ogr


# connect to the database
connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                              password="password",
                              host="localhost",
                              database="example")
# create cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS trial1")
cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE trial1 (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, geom Geometry)")
cursor.execute("CREATE INDEX trial1_index ON trial1 USING GIST(geom)")
print("Successfully created ")
connection.commit()

# define OSMfile path
osm = ogr.Open("pedestrian.osm")
layer = osm.GetLayer(1)

#  delete the existing contents of the table
cursor.execute("DELETE FROM trial1")
print(str(layer.GetFeatureCount()))
for i in range(layer.GetFeatureCount()):
    feature = layer.GetFeature(i)
    # Get feature geometry
    geometry = feature.GetGeometryRef()
    wkt = geometry.ExportToWkt()
    # Insert data into database,
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO trial1 (geom) VALUES (ST_GeomFromText(" + "'" + wkt + "', 4326))")
    print("Data inserted successfully")
connection.commit()
```

expected result:This code should create table in database and also import data into it from given file.currently this code is just creating table .after table creation it dont give error ,it says Process finished with exit code 0.